# Job was updated do not execute the actual code!

Tags: timer-jobs

I have a job (timer job) that was updated but the new code is not executed but the old!!!

I have reseted the Sharpoint Timer, I have reseted the App Pool IIS ... but nothing makes the new job code run... always that I execute the job, the old version is executed!

Anyone knows some tip?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try retracting the solution first.. and make sure the Timer Job is not listed under Central Admin after retraction.. Try rebuilding and deploying the solution and then do IIS Reset and restart SPTimerV4 service

Comment: I have done a IIS RESET and a SharePoint Timer Restart too!

Comment: You have one server or multiple servers? And check the dll's date in GAC to be sure its really updated.